# Не срабатывает next.Line

Tags: java, методы, scanner

Есть такой метод

```
public boolean search(){
      boolean b = false;
        System.out.println("Введите название настолки");
        String result;
        result = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase();   ЗДЕСЬ!!!
        result = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase();   И ЗДЕСЬ!!! 
        for (BoardGame boardGame: allBG){
            if(result.equals(boardGame.getName().toUpperCase())){
                System.out.println(boardGame.toString());
                b = true;
            }
        }
        if (!b){
            b = false;
        }

        return b;
    }
```

если сканнер вызвать два раза как в примере, то все работает, но если оставить одну строчку то почему то пропускает его и программа идет дальше не останавливаясь на считывание. Почему так? Сканнер задекларирован в классе как private переменная, инициализирован в методе который вызывается чуть раньше данного метода.  Также интересно то, что если вызывать метод next() (один раз), то все работает, а также если создать новый объект сканнера в этом методе и у него вызвав nextline() один раз то все тоже будет работать!

Comment: Хорошо бы показать порядок исполнения и как вводятся данные.     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result1 = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase(); //ЗДЕСЬ!!!
        String result2 = scn.nextLine().toUpperCase(); //И ЗДЕСЬ!!!
        System.out.println(result1);
        System.out.println(result2);
    } работает, как и ожидается

Comment: Метод nextLine считывает до символа новой строки (то есть до \n).

Может вы ошибочно вводите данные через пробел?